# Find a pattern in the line of another file in python

Tags: python, database, loops, file, pattern-matching

I'm learning python so I have two files with a lot of lines:

file 1

```
71528
1452
14587
```

file 2

```
country_hoj_17458   9  CA   5    CA 78.4
country_hoj_1452   10  CA   15   CA 96.5
country_hoj_14787  19  CA   51   CA 12.4
country_hoj_15742  19  CA   51   CA 12.4
country_hoj_171528  19  CA   51   CA 12.4
```

I want print the lines where the pattern (number) file 1 matchs with the file 2 in the first column. I want an outfile like this

```
 country_hoj_1452   10  CA   15   CA 96.5
 country_hoj_14787  19  CA   51   CA 12.4
```

my script is like that:

```
filename = numbers.txt
filename2 = data.txt
with open(filename) as f:
    with open (filename2) as m:
        for line in f:
                if line in m:
                       print (m)
```

What I need to fix in it? Anybody can help me and support me? Thanks a lot

Comment: You need to repeat your tutorial materials on string processing.  Learn to use the `in` operator.  Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorial materials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
filename = 'numbers.txt'
filename2 = 'data.txt'

with open(filename) as numberLines:
    with open (filename2) as dataLines:
        nL = numberLines.read().splitlines()
        dL = dataLines.read().splitlines()
        dataReadLines = [j for i in nL for j in dL if i in j]
        #dataReadLines = [i for i in nL]
        print (str(dataReadLines))
```

Another answer where each key is paired with their respective data find. I've changed your inputs and you can easily understand using the below code.

```
from collections import defaultdict

filename = 'numbers.txt'
filename2 = 'data.txt'

with open(filename) as numberLines:
    with open (filename2) as dataLines:
        nL = numberLines.read().splitlines()
        dL = dataLines.read().splitlines()
        defDList = defaultdict(list)
        dataReadLines = [defDList[i].append(j) for i in nL for j in dL if i in j]
        #dataReadLines = [i for i in nL]
        print (defDList)
```